# Hey there I’m sorry to bother but I need some help with my other appl iPhone ID password.the thing is the number is no longer active and I email

Tags: email, apple-id, password

Can anyone help me change my password on my other iPhone I forgot my Apple ID password and I’m no longer using the email even the phone number is not active